# alternating direction method of multipliers for nonlinear inverse problems?

Tags: optimization, inverse-problems

I have a standard inverse problem with L1 regularization:
$\|F(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y}\|^2_2+\alpha\|\mathbf{x}\|_1$, where $F(\mathbf{x})$ is nonlinear. I am wondering if this is a good problem to use ADMM. Or should I just use a usual L1 solver.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us more about $F$?

Comment: I am working on a rather general class of problems. $F:R^n\rightarrow R^m$ is a nonlinear operator, where n and m are high dimensional. I know the inverse problem is highly ill-posed.  Evaluation of $F$ is computationally expensive, involving some a large-scale PDE. Supposedly I can compute its gradient with adjoint methods. thanks.